# how get attribute for a matching predicate using xpath2

Tags: xpath

I have an xml like this:-

```
<include><method wrap="true"><name>methodA</name></method>...</include>
```

method node can have wrap attribute with value true or false. absence of attribute should mean it is false.

my predicate is like this:-

```
//include/method[matches(str, methodA)]
```

to get the matching nodes.
How can I get the wrap attribute and figure if the attribute is missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//include/method[@wrap='true'][name = 'methodA']
```

The test for wrap attribute will only be `true` if there is an attribute wrap and the value is string `true`.

Comment: I am using psychopathprocessor http://wiki.eclipse.org/PsychoPathXPathProcessor/UserManual. Is it possible to first get the method node and query if the wrap attribute is true or false?